# How to implement a method that ignores some input values? (Java)

Tags: java, methods, interface

I'm a total beginner to Java. My first task was to create a simple package of geometric objects - Point, Line, Circle, Rectangle and so on. Everything works fine  but I'm not sure how to accomplish this other task:

> Create a method within this existing file that takes an array of objects and
>   returns a total sum of their areas, but in the cases where they don't
>   have this parameter available (like classes `Line` and `Point`), the
>   method **ignores** these objects.

My guess is that an interface (like `GeometricObject` or maybe `ObjectWithArea`) should be used, but I have no idea how to use it. I was thinking about something like this:

```
public interface ObjectWithArea {

   double sumOfAreas(Array) {

   //this is the declaration of the method
  }

}
```

Here is how I would incorporate the interface into my existing code:

```
class Rectangle implements ObjectWithArea {

   //here are the original parameters and methods of this class

   double sumOfAreas(Array) { 

      //here is the body of the previously declared method

   }
}
```

but this solution doesn't solve the problem that the method should ignore other objects that do not implement this interface. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if (x instanceof ObjectWithArea)` to test if you should ignore an object, and then a cast `((ObjectWithArea)x).getArea()` to act on those that you do need to process.

An alternative that avoids having to do this (`instanceof` is a bit controversial -- but don't get into a fight with your teacher over it), would be to have the `getArea` method on all objects and return `0` for those without an area.